# Selenium webdriver c# - unable to click() element (element not null)

Tags: c#, ajax, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I seem to be having issues clicking a element inside a box which is filled by ajax.

So the web page I am on has a link on it which when clicked this calls a javascript function which then inserts a new div into the page which is full of new content.

Now the weird thing is I can find the element inside this box no problem using xpath, and I can even read its value but! I can't use Click(); on the link inside the box the event just wont work for some reason.

Has anyone faced a similar issue and know a work around?

I am using Selenium webdriver 2.35 with Firefox 23

```
 More Info
```

OK so the HTML for the link I click which calls the JS to make the div appear.

```
<center>
    <a id="link_fleet_move_here" href="">Move fleet here</a>
</center>
<br>
<script>
    $("#link_fleet_move_here").click( function(event) { event.preventDefault(); load_fleet_move_to_destination("fleet.aspx?method=ajax&view=move_to_destination&version=1&player=111&destination=LZLOCATION"); $("#link_fleet_move_here").hide();} )
</script>
<center>
<div id="fleetLoaderTemplate" style="display:none">
<div id="fleetLoaderErrorTemplate" style="display:none">
</center>
<div id="move_to_destination_container"></div>
```

And when the event finishes loading the new HTML

```
<div id="move_to_destination_container">
    <ajax>
        <table width="600" align="center">
        BIG TABLE FULL OF CONTENT
        <td sorttable_customkey="LZLOCATION">
            <a href="map.aspx?loc=LZLOCATION">(LZLOCATION)</a>
        </td>
        <td sorttable_customkey=""></td>
        <td sorttable_customkey=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="fleet.aspx?fleet=&view=move&destination=AnotherLocation">Move</a>
        </td>
        <table>
    <br>
    </ajax>
</div>
```

The Selector

```
location = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, '" + LZLocation + "')]/following::td[3]"));
location.Click();
```

I think it may be something to do with that div actually, I think it starts as Display:None and gets changed, this will be effecting it?

I thought it was dynamically adding it but maybe not!

Comment: I'm going to guess that the `click()` performs some javascript. Try performing the click via the Actions API, or javascript.  Occasionally you have to do such a workaround.

Comment: I'm not talking about Webdriver using Javascript, but that the page has a javascript event attached to the button.  Cast the driver to a JavascriptExecutor, and then try to perform the click from there.

Comment: Well no I click a link which fires some JS and that JS adds a new div to the page and then I select a link inside this new div, I can find this element and even return its text/value/atributes but Click() wont click it. The element is just an <a> link to another page not attached to any JS.

Comment: Can you post some HTML then, and the selector you are using?  It may be that you are selecting the wrong element.

Comment: ok posted I think its somthing to do with CSS to be honest. But I thought as long as I can see it which I can selenium could see it :/ I mean it finds it ok.

Comment: I don't see any CSS there, nor do I see a link element.  Can you post the HTML of the link that is dynamically loaded?

Comment: Actually looking at it theres no CSS applied to that div, its just empty until that JS populates it by Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting your element via the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#move_to_destination_container a[href^='fleet']")).click();
```

If it throws an error, try using:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#move_to_destination_container a[href^='fleet']"))).click();
```

Comment: Sorry to keep annoying you but what will that click? because the div that is generated contains a huge list of links in a table and that xpath selector I did is the only thing that finds the correct link I want to click.